# Best and Fastest way to insert milions records in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I want to insert 5 million unique random numbers in the oracle table. each random number has 8 digits. here is my code

```
DECLARE I INT;
J INT;
gen_coupen varchar2(8);
check_coupen varchar2(8);

 BEGIN

 j :=1;

FOR I IN J..:TO_COUPEN LOOP
select round(dbms_random.value(10000000,99999999),0) into :gen_coupen from dual;

    select count(*) into :check_coupen from registration where coupen=:gen_coupen;
    if (:check_coupen=0) and LENGTH(:gen_coupen)=8 then
  insert into registration (coupen)
    values(:gen_coupen);
    commit;
end if;
```

this code works fine but it takes so much time to insert is there any fastest way to insert 5 milions records.

Comment: With :TO_COUPEN you set a maximum value, say 5M. Then, depending on the random results, you insert something between 1 and 5M rows, with an expected value of around 4.86M rows. Is this intended?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes u r right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row-by-row really is slow. Do it *at once*, if you can; I can't, I don't have enough memory so I'm doing it in loop, but 1 million rows at a time. Here's how:

```
SQL> create table registration (coupen number);

Table created.

SQL> set timing on
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 5 loop
  3      insert into registration (coupen)
  4      select round(dbms_random.value(10000000,99999999),0) coupen
  5      from dual
  6      connect by level <= 1000000;
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:17.96
SQL> set timing off
SQL> select count(*) From registration;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   5000000

SQL>
```

Took ~18 seconds on my laptop and 11g XE database.

---

If it has to be 5 million distinct values, then code has to be somewhat changed. I'd suggest you to

- insert some more rows (more than 5 million) (don't try to avoid duplicates at insert stage, it'll take too much time for that many rows)
- delete duplicates
- delete superfluous rows (so that 5 million rows remain)

Here's one option (I included counts and timings to show what's going on with number of rows and to see how much time it takes).

```
create table registration (coupen number);
set serveroutput on
set timing on

declare
  l_cnt    number;
  l_cntdis number;
begin
  -- initial insert
  dbms_output.put_line('Stage 1: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss'));
  for i in 1 .. 5 loop
    insert into registration (coupen)
    select round(dbms_random.value(10000000,99999999),0) coupen
    from dual
    connect by level <= 1050000;    --> more than 1 million rows per loop iteration (because of duplicates)
  end loop;
  commit;

  select count(*), count(distinct coupen) 
  into l_cnt, l_cntdis
  from registration;
  dbms_output.put_line('Stage 2: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' total = ' || l_cnt ||', distinct = ' || l_cntdis);

  execute immediate 'create index i1reg_coup on registration (coupen)';
  dbms_output.put_line('Stage 3: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss'));

  -- delete remaining duplicates
  delete from registration a
  where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
                   from registration b
                   where b.coupen = a.coupen
                  );
  select count(*), count(distinct coupen) 
  into l_cnt, l_cntdis
  from registration;
  dbms_output.put_line('Stage 4: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' total = ' || l_cnt ||', distinct = ' || l_cntdis);

  -- delete superfluous rows (i.e. leave exactly 5.000.000 distinct rows)
  delete from registration r
  where r.coupen in 
  (select x.coupen from 
    (select a.coupen, 
            row_number() over (order by null) rn
     from registration a
    ) x 
   where x.rn > 5000000
  );                 
  select count(*), count(distinct coupen) 
  into l_cnt, l_cntdis
  from registration;
  dbms_output.put_line('Stage 5: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') || ' total = ' || l_cnt ||', distinct = ' || l_cntdis);
end;
/
```

Result:

```
Stage 1: 11:06:49
Stage 2: 11:07:09 total = 5250000, distinct = 5100332
Stage 3: 11:07:18
Stage 4: 11:11:17 total = 5100332, distinct = 5100332
Stage 5: 11:12:02 total = 5000000, distinct = 5000000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:05:13.57
SQL>
```

Slightly over 5 minutes on the same laptop and 11g XE. See if this is acceptable in your case.

Comment: it gives so many duplicates records I need unique records only

Comment: @user757321: Then delete them. E.g.: `delete from registration r where exists (select null from registration r2 where r2.coupen = r.coupen and r2.rowid < r.rowid);`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner 136501 records deleted.i need exactly 50,00000 records

Comment: @user757321: You said in your request "this code works". I said that you would get less then 5M rows and asked whether this was intended. You didn't decline. Now you suddenly do need an exact number of rows. This asks for a completely different approach.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: I added another option which takes care about **duplicates** and **exactly 5 million rows**. Have a look, please.